# AwsS3 client throws error on initialization

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-java-sdk, aws-sdk-java-2.0

I am seeing this crash whenever I am trying to initialize aws s3 client. I tried looking for solutions but didn't found any.

```
BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(amazonAccessId, amazonSecretKey);
Amazon S3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
            .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
            .withRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTH_1)
            .build();
```

Gradle file

```
dependencies {
      implementation platform('com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-bom:1.11.641')
      implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:1.11.641'
}
```

This throws an error on .build() line saying Failed resolution of: Ljavax/management/MBeanServerFactory;

```
--------- beginning of crash
2019-09-30 17:48:02.148 20191-20191/com.tactopus.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tactopus.app, PID: 20191
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljavax/management/MBeanServerFactory;
        at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.getMBeanServer(MBeans.java:111)
        at com.amazonaws.jmx.MBeans.registerMBean(MBeans.java:50)
        at com.amazonaws.jmx.SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.registerMetricAdminMBean(SdkMBeanRegistrySupport.java:27)
        at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.registerMetricAdminMBean(AwsSdkMetrics.java:398)
        at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.<clinit>(AwsSdkMetrics.java:359)
        at com.amazonaws.metrics.AwsSdkMetrics.addAll(AwsSdkMetrics.java:662)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.<clinit>(AmazonS3Client.java:406)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:35)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Builder$1.apply(AmazonS3Builder.java:32)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:64)
        at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder.build(AmazonS3ClientBuilder.java:28)
        at com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsSyncClientBuilder.build(AwsSyncClientBuilder.java:46)
        at com.tactopus.app.AWS.S3DownloadAndUpdate.init(S3DownloadAndUpdate.java:98)
        at com.tactopus.app.AWS.S3DownloadAndUpdate.<init>(S3DownloadAndUpdate.java:64)
        at com.tactopus.app.presenter.BookDescriptionActivityPresenter.onClick(BookDescriptionActivityPresenter.java:46)
        at com.tactopus.app.view.BookDescriptionActivity$3.onClick(BookDescriptionActivity.java:166)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7352)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:14177)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7318)
        at android.view.View.access$3200(View.java:846)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27800)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7050)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:965)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "javax.management.MBeanServerFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.tactopus.app-IcaP3SsuBAnlY85tNBJ8fw==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.tactopus.app-IcaP3SsuBAnlY85tNBJ8fw==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
```

Comment: What version of the Android SDK? And where are you running this from? Google app engine? Emulated phones?

Comment: I am running this from my physical device. Android version 28.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem today, it looks like `MBeanServerFactory` isn't a part of AWS's Java SDK.

Use the following dependencies instead

```
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.6.0'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2.0'
implementation 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.0'
```

You can use `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` to initialize your `AmazonS3` client. Go to your [Amazon Cognito Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/cognito/home), then create an Identity Pool. Make sure you have given the correct permissions (you can check by going to your IAM Dashboard, then under the 'Roles' tab, check for your Identity Pool that you just created and add the AmazonS3FullAccess policy).

After you have created the Identity Pool, you will get sample code that looks like this

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider;
credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
    getApplicationContext(),
    "ap-southeast-1:xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", // Identity Pool ID
    Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1 // Region
);
```

Use this `credentialsProvider` object to initialize your `AmazonS3` client

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
```

Comment: Yes with this dependency it is working. The reason I am using Java SDK is that it has a transfer manager which helps in downloading the whole directory at once.

Comment: Great answer, that was very helpful for me! I was using the Java SDK and I had this problem additionally to a very dex count toll, using this library instead solves both problems. Thank you.

Comment: @AyushMalviya how did you solve the issue and be able to use the TransferManager on android? I have the same problem here